# Remove certain words in string from column in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R that lists out a bunch of company names and want to remove words like "Inc", "Company", "LLC", etc. for part of a clean-up effort. I have the following sample data:

sampleData

```
  Location             Company
1 New York, NY         XYZ Company
2 Chicago, IL          Consulting Firm LLC
3 Miami, FL            Smith & Co.
```

Words I do not want to include in my output:

```
stopwords = c("Inc","inc","co","Co","Inc.","Co.","LLC","Corporation","Corp","&")
```

I built the following function to break out each word, remove the stopwords, and then bring the words back together, but it is not iterating through each row of the dataset.

```
removeWords <- function(str, stopwords) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(str, " "))
  paste(x[!x %in% stopwords], collapse = " ")
}

removeWords(sampleData$Company,stopwords)
```

The output for the above function looks like this:

```
[1] "XYZ Company Consulting Firm Smith"
```

T
he output should be:

```
 Location              Company
1 New York, NY         XYZ Company
2 Chicago, IL          Consulting Firm
3 Miami, FL            Smith
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use 'tm' package

```
library(tm)

stopwords = readLines('stopwords.txt')     #Your stop words file
x  = df$company        #Company column data
x  =  removeWords(x,stopwords)     #Remove stopwords

df$company_new <- x     #Add the list as new column and check
```

Answer (score 6):

With a little check on the stopwords( having inserted "\" in Co. to avoid regex, spaces ): (But the previous answer should be preferred if you dont want to keep an eye on stopwords)

```
 stopwords = c("Inc","inc","co ","Co ","Inc."," Co\\.","LLC","Corporation","Corp","&")

 gsub(paste0(stopwords,collapse = "|"),"", df$Company)
[1] "XYZ Company"      "Consulting Firm " "Smith "       

df$Company <- gsub(paste0(stopwords,collapse = "|"),"", df$Company)
# df
#      Location          Company
#1 New York, NY      XYZ Company
#2  Chicago, IL Consulting Firm 
#3    Miami, FL           Smith
```