# Remove words from string by not affecting the other name that has that word in it

Tags: r

```
CompanyName            Desired Output
Abbey Company.Com      abbey company
Manisd Company .com    manisd company
Idely.com              idely
```

How can i remove .com,while taking care that "com" from company is not effected.
I've tried the below code

```
     stopwords = c("limited"," l.c.", " llc","corporation"," &"," ltd.","llp ",
                      "l.l.c","incorporated","association","s.p.a"," l.p.","l.l.l.p","p.a  ","p.c  ",
                      "chtd  ","chtd.  ","r.l.l.l.p  ","rlllp  ", "the "," lmft", " inc.", ".com")

   file_new1$CompanyName<-gsub(paste0(stopwords,collapse = "|"),"", file_new1$CompanyName)
```

already refereed to this link

[Remove certain words in string from column in dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901100/remove-certain-words-in-string-from-column-in-dataframe-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have:

```
CompanyName <- c("Abbey Company.Com", "Manisd Company .com", "Idely.com")
```

You could try:

```
gsub(paste0(gsub("\\.","\\\\.",stopwords),collapse = "|"),"",
     tolower(CompanyName))
#[1] "abbey company"   "manisd company " "idely"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do `gsub("\\.Com","",dt$CompanyName)`. Assuming that your `data.table` is called `dt`

**UPDATE**

Another solution might be to keep only the "stuff" before the dot (".").

So

```
CompanyName <- data.table(V1=c("Abbey Company.Com", "Manisd Company .com", "Idely.com"))

> CompanyName
                    V1
1:   Abbey Company.Com
2: Manisd Company .com
3:           Idely.com

CompanyName$V1 <- sel_strsplit(CompanyName$V1,"\\.",1)
> CompanyName
                V1
1:   Abbey Company
2: Manisd Company 
3:           Idely
```

That way you don't have to care if you have ".com", or ".COM", or ".co.uk" etc

Comment: this is what i'll have to do for different formate of "com,.com,.Com, Inc.,inc,inc." Any other shorter way?