# How to remove specific words in a column

Tags: r, string, tm, tidytext

I have a Column consisting of several Country Offices associated a with a company, where I would like to shorten fx: China Country Office and Bangladesh Country Office, to just China or Bangladesh- In other words removing the words "Office" and "Country" from the column called Imp_Office.

I tried using the tm-package, with reference to an earlier post, but nothing happened.

**what I wrote:**

```
library(tm)
stopwords = c("Office", "Country","Regional")
MY_df$Imp_Office <- gsub(paste0(stopwords, collapse = "|","", 
MY_df$Imp_Office))
```

**Where I got the following error message:**

```
  Error in gsub(paste0(stopwords, collapse = "|", "", MY_df$Imp_Office)) 
    : 
      argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I also tried using the function readLines:

```
stopwords = readLines("Office", "Country","Regional")
MY_df$Imp_Office <- gsub(paste0(stopwords, collapse = "|","", 
MY_df$Imp_Office))
```

But this didn't help either

I have considered the possibility of using some other string manipulation method, but I don't need to detect, replace or remove whitespace - so I am kind of lost here.

Thank you.

Comment: You've got a misplaced closing bracket. `Complete_df$Imp_Office <- gsub(paste0(stopwords, collapse = "|"), "", 
Complete_df$Imp_Office)`

Comment: gsub(paste0(stopwords, collapse = "|"),"",Complete_df$Imp_Office)..you need a paranthesis to close the paste function

Comment: Solution for previously asked [Remove certain words in string from column in dataframe...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901100/remove-certain-words-in-string-from-column-in-dataframe-in-r) may help.

Answer (score 12):

First, let's set up a dataframe with a column like what you describe:

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- data_frame(Imp_Office = c("China Country Office",
                                "Bangladesh Country Office",
                                "China",
                                "Bangladesh"))
df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   Imp_Office               
#>   <chr>                    
#> 1 China Country Office     
#> 2 Bangladesh Country Office
#> 3 China                    
#> 4 Bangladesh
```

Then we can use `str_remove_all()` from the stringr package to remove any bits of text that you don't want from them.

```r
df %>%
    mutate(Imp_Office = str_remove_all(Imp_Office, " Country| Office"))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   Imp_Office
#>   <chr>     
#> 1 China     
#> 2 Bangladesh
#> 3 China     
#> 4 Bangladesh
```

Created on 2018-04-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: One thing to consider could be to use "[ ]" as it was suggested: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_remove . So df %>%
    mutate(Imp_Office = str_remove_all(Imp_Office, " [Country| Office]"))